# How to add a comma every 4 spaces for only specific column

Tags: excel

I have two columns of data that have years going down about 2700 rows. The numbers are model years for vehicles, each row has multiple years and shows up in excel as 201220092010200820072011 or in scientific notation. I tried marking the entire column as text but it didn't work. Anyways, I would like to have it look like this 2012,2009,2010,2008,2007,2011

Some rows may only have two years other rows may have 5 - 7 different years even 8. How could I do this going all the way down the entire column for the 2700 rows?

Thanks guys!

Comment: The values that show up in scientific notation will not be recoverable.  The column needs to be marked as text BEFORE entering the long strings of digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Your_Solution()

Dim yearColl, newStr(), fullString As String
yearColl = Range("A1").Text
fullString = ""

ReDim newStr(Len(yearColl) - 1)
For i = 0 To Len(yearColl) - 1
    newStr(i) = Mid(yearColl, i + 1, 1)
    fullString = fullString & newStr(i)
    If i Mod 4 = 3 Then
        fullString = fullString & ","
    End If
Next

Range("A2").Value = fullString

End Sub
```